# Sufficiency of KKT conditions when the objective function is convex on the interior of feasible set

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Consider the optimization problem
$$
\min_{x\in X} f(x)
$$
where $X\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is a nonempty closed convex set. $f$ is continuous everywhere on $X$. I can show that $f$ is convex on the *interior* of $X$.  I don't have a proof that $f$ is convex on the boundary of $X$. Are the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions sufficient to characterize a solution to this optimization problem in this case?

Comment: What are the KKT conditions for this problem?

Comment: Is $f$ even continuous? How is the behaviour on the boundary related to that on the interior? Is the interior non empty?

Comment: I think you need to define some more conditions on $f$, for example continuity. In this case, you are pretty safe.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören: Yes $f$ is actually continuous on $X$. I forgot to include that information initially. I've updated the question.

Comment: @copper.hat: Yes $f$ is continuous. The interior of $X$ is also non empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, Indeed we have $$\text{Set of optimal solutions} = \text{Set of KKT points} $$  If $f$ is continuous on $X$ while convex on $\text{int} X$, then $f$ has to be Convex on whole $X$. Also we know that $\text{int} X \neq \emptyset$ this shows the **slater** QC holds , therefore aevery optimal point is indeed **KKT** point. we show that also each **KKT** point is indeed optimal. To this end, take $\bar{x} \in X$ which satisfies KKT system i.e., $$ 0 \in \partial f( \bar{x} ) + N(\bar{x}; X)$$
Where $N(\bar{x}; X)$ and $\partial f(x)$ are the convex normal cone of $X$ at $\bar{x},$ and convex subdifferential of $f$ at $\bar {x}$ respectively.  Depending on the structure of constraints $N(\bar{x}; X)$ can be reduced to the a system containing Lagrange multipliers. From KKT condition we could find vectors $u \in \partial f(\bar{x})$ and $ v \in N(\bar{x}; X)$ such that$$u + v =0$$

Now take $x \in X$, Since $u \in \partial f(\bar {x})$ we have

\begin{align*}
\langle u , x -\bar {x} \rangle  \leq  f(x ) - f(\bar{x}) \\
\Rightarrow \langle v , x -\bar {x} \rangle  \ge  f(\bar{x}) - f(x ) 
\end{align*}

And that the left side is negative due to $v \in N(\bar{x} ; X)$, Hence $f(x) \ge f(\bar{x}).$ Therefore $\bar{x} \in X$ is optimal.

Note that the continuity of $f$ on boundary of $X$ is an essential assumption!

For example take $X=[0,1]$ and $f=1$ on $\text{int}X = (0,1)$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x \in \{0, 1\}$ Then all point living on $(0,1)$ are **KKT** points, Since for $\bar{x} \in (0,1)$we have $f' (\bar{x}) =0 $  (note that in interior points all Lagrange multipliers are zero, that's why KKT system is reduced to $f' = 0.$ On the other hand, clearly none of these points are optimal!

P.S:

Actually what I mentioned here as Slater QC is not the well-known **Slater's Constraint's Qualification** (of course $X$ has  not been represented by inequalities and equalities), Maybe I should delete that word to avoid confusion.
 It is a **slater type** qualification condition (QC) which guarantees Sum Rule i.e, 
$$    \partial (f+g) (x) =   \partial f(x) +  \partial g (x)    $$
Where $g$ is the indicator function of $X$, so $\partial g(\bar{x}) = N(\bar{x} ; X)$. And note that the constrained problem is equivalent to unconstrained problem with new objective $f+g$. That's why we have the implication $  Optimal \to KKT $. In general Somehow all constraint qualifications can be seen as conditions guarantee **Sum rule**  between objective function and the indicator function of Constraint set. I used **sum rule** under condition made in **Moreu-Rockafellar**  theorem, which corresponds to Slater's constraint qualification. There are also some other conditions for calculus rules which somehow they have counter part in Constraint Qualification and vice versa!

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is clearly correct but I forgot to add an important piece of information: $f$ is continuous on the whole set $X$! Sorry about that. I have updated the question.

Comment: @user_lambda  Look at my updated answer

Comment: Can you give some references where the optimality condition you wrote down is called a "KKT system" and where the condition int($X$)$\neq \emptyset$" is called Slater's constraint qualification? I don't think I've seen this terminology used in this way.

Comment: Actually KKT conditions are for smooth problems, with equality and inequality constraints, but what I wrote here is a straightforward generalization of KKT conditions to a general non-smooth problem with geometric constraint, which is reduce to the traditional KKT if $f$  be smooth and $X$ identified via equality an inequality conditions, If OP, would have written question in that form I would use original KKT. I believe what I wrote is called KKT type condition (or generalized KKT) I saw in a paper, and I also my advisor (Boris Mordukhovich)  calls  it KKT ! same true for slater QC. @littleO

Comment: @Ashkan Thanks. If $X$ has empty interior, what is "Slater's condition" in that case?

Comment: @littleO If X has empty interior, then Slater constraint qualification is not satisfied.  There may or may not be some other constraint qualification satisfied in that case.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone But, for a typical convex optimization problem with linear equality constraints $Ax = b$ in addition to convex inequalty constraints $f_i(x) \leq 0$ (for $i = 1,\ldots,n$), Slater's condition is typically satisfied even though the set $X = \{ x \mid Ax = b, f_i(x) \leq 0 \text{ for } i = 1,\ldots, n \}$ has empty interior.  In this case Slater's condition merely requires the existence of a point $x$ such that $Ax = b$ and $f_i(x) < 0$ for all $i$. So I believe your comment is not consistent with the standard usage of the term "Slater's condition".

Comment: @ littleO Yes, I was a a little sloppy. For Slater condition, interior only has to exist relative to nonlinear constraints. No need to worry about linear constraints as far as constraint qualifications go.

Comment: But it seems that Ashkan is attempting to generalize "Slater's condition" to the case where the constraints are expressed simply as $x \in X$, where $x$ is any closed convex set, and I am wondering how this generalization of Slater's condition can be stated precisely (and if it really can be stated precisely after all).  @Ashkan

Comment: @little  I added some explanation  to the answer.

Comment: @Ashkan Thank you.  I don't mean to be discouraging you from using this terminology -- rather, I like your attempt to generalize Slater's condition to the more general case, because it seems potentially to be a very clear way to understand these ideas.  That's why I'm so interested in understanding this.  As it stands now, the requirement that  int($X$) is nonempty seems to be overly strict, and does not reduce to Slater's condition in the case where $X$ is described by inequalities and equalities.  Can you come up with a different, weaker condition which truly generalizes Slater's condition?

Comment: @Ashkan "In general Somehow all constraint qualifications can be seen as conditions guarantee Sum rule between objective function and the indicator function of Constraint set."  This is a great sentence, very enlightening.

Comment: This is really good question, it deserves to be asked in separate question.
How to generalize the slater CQ to general convex geometric constraint . @littleO

Comment: @Redshoes would you be able to help with this question that I posted here? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2567198/finding-tangent-cone-of-a-convex-set You seem to be extremely well-versed on all the constraint qualification conditions, and I think they come into play when determining the tangent cone in this question, but I'm not sure exactly how. Thanks ahead of time! :)