# Finding Tangent Cone of a Convex Set

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, operations-research, convex-cone

Consider the problem $$\text{minimize}\,\,\, -8x_{1}+x_{2} \\ \text{subject to}\,\,\,\,\,x_{2} \leq 8, \\ (x_{1}-4)^{2} - x_{2} \leq 8 $$

By using the method of Lagrange multipliers, I found the optimal point to occur at $\hat{x} = (x_{1},x_{2}) = (8,8)$ with multiplier vector $\hat{\lambda}=(0,1)$.

I was able to show after the fact that the problem satisfies the Linear Independence Constraint Qualification (LICQ), since the gradients of the constraint functions evaluated at $\hat{x}$ are linearly independent. And so, $\hat{x}$ does satisfy the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker (KKT) conditions - i.e., these first-order necessary conditions for optimality are satisfied.

Also, since the problem is convex, these conditions are also sufficient to determine optimality.

The next thing that I need to do, and w**hat I need help with is finding the tangent cone to the feasible set at the optimal solution** $\hat{x} = (8,8)$.

My notes/text defines the **tangent cone** as the set $T_{X}(x)$ of all tangent directions for $X \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ at $x\in X$. And, a direction $d$ is called **tangent** to a set $X \subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ at the point $x \in X$ and scalars $\tau_{k}>0$, $k = 1,2, \cdots $ such that $\tau_{k} \downarrow 0$ and $$d = \lim_{k \to \infty}\frac{x^{k}-x}{\tau_{k}}.$$

It also defines the tangent cone as the closure of the cone of feasible directions at $x \in X$: $$ T_{X}(x) = \overline{K_{X}(x)}= \overline{cone(X-x)}, $$ where $cone(X-x)$ is the cone generated by the convex set $X$.

The feasible set in question here IS convex, and below is a sketch of it:

[image]

The arrows indicate the direction in which I **think** the tangent cone is supposed to go, but I'm not sure. Could somebody please help me with this? Unfortunately, I'm still not confident when it comes to figuring out tangent cones...

I was thinking maybe I should first find the tangent line at that point, but then where do I go from there? And how will the constraint qualification conditions come into play?

Thank you ahead of time.

Comment: What I see in picture  it seems you only think about feasible directions rather than tangent directions. Tangent cone is slightly bigger than feasible cone.
You draw the tangent lines to the constraint at point $\bar{x}$ then the enclosed area between these lines gives you the tangent cone.

Try it prove it mathematically

Comment: @Redshoes I guess my problem is I don't know how to prove it mathematically. Should I try to show that $\langle \nabla g_{i}, d \rangle \leq 0$ for all the active constraints? (All of the constraints are active this time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the optimal point, the slope of the parabola is $8$.
Thus, from your pictures, it is clear that $T_X(8,8)$ is the convex cone generated by the vectors $(-1,0)$ and $(-1,-8)$, i.e.,
$$T_X(8,8) = \big\{ \alpha(-1,0)+\beta(-1,-8) \mid \alpha\geq 0,\beta\geq 0\big\}.$$

Comment: my prof hinted that the constraint qualification conditions as well as which constraints are active or inactive come into play in the formulation of that answer. Could you please explain why?

Comment: If you look at the quadratic constraint alone, the tangent cone is a half space through $(8,8)$ tangential to that point. However, the other linear constraint is active and this cuts the half space into the cone described above.

Comment: there is a quadratic programming problem I have been stuck on for 4 days. Basically, once I have rewritten the Lagrangian so that it is no longer in terms of $x$, I cannot figure out how to find its sup so that I can derive the dual problem. Could you please help? There is a 100 point bounty on the question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2571031/need-help-setting-up-and-solving-dual-problem